# Perl-How to split a line based on different length of characters

Tags: perl, split

I want to split a line based on multiple character lengths and store them in separate variables.
For ex:`$myString = "Mickey      24                    USA alive`
Here first 12 characters are username, next 2 are age, next 23 characters are country and next 7 are status.
So is there a way to save them separately store them using `split()` or `s///`?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex to match, or a [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

```
my $myString = "Mickey      24                    USA alive";

if ($myString =~ /(.{12})(.{2})(.{23})(.*)/) {
    $name = $1;
    $age = $2;
    $country = $3;
    $status = $4;

    print "<$name><$age><$country><$status>";

} else {
    warn "line not long enough"; 
}
```

Outputs:

```
<Mickey      ><24><                    USA>< alive>
```

To strip spacing from the variables after the fact, just use another regex:

```
$value =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

Can even do that in a single line using:

```
s/^\s+|\s+$//g for ($name, $age, $country, $status);
```

Answer (score 8):

Unpacking fixed-width fields is most simply and efficiently done using the [`unpack` built-in function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html).

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $my_string = 'Mickey      24                    USA alive';

my ($username, $age, $country, $status) = unpack 'a12 a2 a23 a7', $my_string;

print <<__END_OUTPUT__;
"$username"
"$age"
"$country"
"$status"
__END_OUTPUT__
```

**output**

```
"Mickey      "
"24"
"                    USA"
" alive"
```

Comment: There is an excellent comparison between regular expressions and unpack in [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Packing-Text). Well worth reading IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Toady's been busy on this one. Roll your own with unpack, as described above by previous posters or perhaps use one from the selection of CPAN modules that make this sort of work a snap.

- https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::FixedLength
- https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::FixedLength

Also available 
- Data::FixedFormat 
- AnyData::Format::Fixed
- Text::FixedWidth

Answer (score -1):

If you have fixed width fields use unpack.

Something like:

```
my ($username, $age, $country, $status) = unpack("A12A2A23A7", $myString);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @TomFenech Actually, it does answer the question, albeit poorly. A code example would make this a much better answer. Something like: `my ($username, $age, $country, $status) = unpack("A12A2A23A7", $myString);`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I should have written my own comment rather than use one of the pre-written options. My point was that the answer, as it stands, would be better as a comment. Your example looks useful and would improve the quality of the answer.